# How to use specify version of ruby for shell script with rbenv?

Tags: ruby

I'm going to write some short script in ruby.
And I want to specify ruby version by shebang or in another way.

I'll use the script in many environments.
I'm using rbenv in the evironments, but it's not sure which version of ruby is installed.

The script must fail if the specify version of ruby is not installed.

How can I do it? Is there good way that I should follow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/ruby-local-exec) it sounds like you just need to prefix your scripts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

And then do one of the following things to tell `rbenv` which version of Ruby to use:

*excerpt: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv*

> Choosing the Ruby Version
>
> When you execute a shim, `rbenv` determines which Ruby version to use by reading it from the following sources, in this order:
>
> 1. The `RBENV_VERSION` environment variable, if specified. You can use the `rbenv` shell command to set this environment variable in your current shell session.
> 2. The first `.ruby-version` file found by searching the directory of the script you are executing and each of its parent directories until reaching the root of your filesystem.
> 3. The first `.ruby-version` file found by searching the current working directory and each of its parent directories until reaching the root of your filesystem. You can modify the `.ruby-version` file in the current working directory with the `rbenv` local command.
> 4. The global `~/.rbenv/version` file. You can modify this file using the `rbenv` global command. If the global version file is not present, `rbenv` assumes you want to use the "system" Ruby—i.e. whatever version would be run if `rbenv` weren't in your path.

You can then use this command to create a `.ruby-version` file in the directory along with the Ruby script.

```
$ rbenv local 1.9.3-p327
```

Comment: Deprecated now; Per doc specified; Now, when you run scripts or binstubs in an application with a .ruby-version file, rbenv will automatically use the application's specified Ruby version, regardless of what directory they're run from.